# DatePicker unescaped latin alphabet character n date-fns - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, calendar, material-ui

I got this error trying to render the DatePicker from Material UI into my react project.

Besides everyone saying it's a version problem what really **solved my problem was set a value into the DatePicker component**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set with some variable contained into your project like this:

**value = {yourVariable} or value = {""} just for test**

```
 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <Grid container justify="space-around">
              <KeyboardDatePicker
                disableToolbar
                variant="inline"
                format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                margin="normal"
                id="date-picker-inline"
                label="Date picker inline"
                value={""}
                KeyboardButtonProps={{
                  "aria-label": "change date",
                }}
              />{" "}
            </Grid>{" "}
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```